# Start Internet Explorer on debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am currently write an ASP.NET WebApplication in Visual Studio 2010. My default browser is Firefox. If I start an WebApplication, the WebApplication starts up in the same instance of Firefox. How is it possible to avoid it? How do I configure Visual Studio that the WebApplicaton starts in an *new* instance of Internet Explorer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Right click on a .aspx page in your solution explorer

2) Select the "browse with" context menu option

3) In the dialog you can select or add a browser.  If you want Firefox in the list, click "add" and point to the firefox.exe filename

4) Click the "Set as Default" button to make this the default browser when you run any page on the site.

By Scott Gu

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on any web page in your solution (.aspx file is fine)
2. Select "Browse With..."
3. Highlight the browser you would like to use
4. Choose "Set as Default"

Now whenever you start debugging, it should use your default browser.

Note you can also click "Add..." in this dialog to add more browser options to the dialog.

EDIT: To make this always open up in a new instance, check your Internet Explorer settings (Tools > Internet Options > General > Tabs > Settings > Open Links From Other Programs In: )